# Mysql query optimise

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Mysql query takes 15+ sec to fetch data. I have given my query below.

**FYI:** messages table has **5L** (500,000) rows of data so it takes long time.

```
select  distinct
        ur.id, ur.user_name as name, ur.online, ur.chat_status,
        ur.updated_at, ur.profile_image, ur.role_id, 
        ( SELECT  created_at
            from  messages
            where  from_role_user_id = ur.id
              OR  to_role_user_id = ur.id
            Order by  created_at DESC
            LIMIT  1
        ) as message_at, 
        ( SELECT  count(is_read)
            from  messages
            where  from_role_user_id = ur.id
              AND  to_role_user_id = 1
              AND  is_read = 0
        ) as count,
        r.name as role
    from  role_users ur
    left join  roles r  ON r.id = ur.role_id
    where  ur.id != 1
      AND  r.name IN ('superadmin', 'candidate', 'admin', 'manager',
                      'business_unit','client')
      AND  ur.chat_status != 'offline'
      AND  ur.is_deleted = 0
      AND  ur.user_name IS NOT NULL
    order by  message_at DESC
    LIMIT  10;
```

Can any one help me to optmize the query.

Comment: What's 5L rows ?

Comment: 5L means 5 lakhs rows of data

Comment: Please  update the question and run explain before your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first subquery would probably be faster this way:

  ```
    ( SELECT  MAX(created_at)
        from  messages
        where  from_role_user_id = ur.id
           OR  to_role_user_id = ur.id
    ) as message_at,
  ```
- This may be even faster:

  ```
    SELECT GREATEST(
               ( SELECT MAX(created_at)  FROM messages
                   WHERE from_role_user_id = ur.id ),
               ( SELECT MAX(created_at)  FROM messages
                   WHERE to_role_user_id = ur.id ) )
  ```
- with two indexes:

  INDEX(from_role_user_id, created_at),
  INDEX(to_role_user_id, created_at)
- `COUNT(x)` counts how many rows have `x IS NOT NULL`.  `SUM(y)` adds up the y's, ignoring `NULLs`.  The usual way to count rows is `COUNT(*)`.

  ```
    ( SELECT  count(*)
        from  messages
        where  from_role_user_id = ur.id
          AND  to_role_user_id = 1
          AND  is_read = 0
    ) as count,
  ```
- And have `INDEX(from_role_user_id, to_role_user_id, is_read)
- If the `DISTINCT` is not really needed, it will avoid an extra pass over the data, hence faster.
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`
- It *may* be better to find the ids of the 10 messages first, then go to the effort of running those subqueries on ly 10 times.